# Calculated and converted field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, primary-key, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated field in SQL such that when a record is created in the table I capture the primary key `Id` of this record and it is saved in a new field of the same record but of `varchar` type.

But I don't know how to implement it. Also the new field must stay in persistence.

Thank you,

Comment: (1) Please share the current `create table` statement for your table. (2) Why do you want to do that?

Comment: And please show some sample data to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a persisted computed column. The syntax in SQL Server goes like:

```
create table mytable (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    val varchar(5),
    charid as convert(varchar(10), id) persisted
);
```

`charid` is the computed column. I used an identity column as primary key, but it does not need to be `identity` for the code to work.

Now say you insert a new record like so:

```
insert into mytable (val) values ('foo');
```

The content of the table is:

```
id | val | charid
-: | :-- | :-----
 1 | foo | 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17fce63ad668a08f9adaef3433a0912a)**